# Lambda Deployment using CodePipeline and CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I'm using CDK and am trying to define a CodePipeline that triggers a Lambda Deployment. It doesn't seem as if there are any CDK constructs to achieve this.

I could only find [CodeDeployEcsDeployAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeDeployEcsDeployAction.html) and [CodeDeployServerDeployAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeDeployServerDeployAction.html).

**The problems are:**

- CodeDeployEcsDeployAction: asks for an ECS task definition
- CodeDeployServerDeployAction: only accepts an artifact `input` for properties. However, it won't pick up the `appspec` file I have defined in the artifact and there are no properties to define the path

(There is no way to do `artifact.atPath('appspec.json')`)

(Submitted [issue 20782](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/20782) just in case this is an actual request)

Here's my Lambda CodeDeploy setup

```js
        const application = new codedeploy.LambdaApplication(
            this,
            'CodeDeployLambdaApplication',
            {
                applicationName: 'LambdaApplication',
            },
        );

        const lambdaDeploymentGroup = new codedeploy.LambdaDeploymentGroup(
            this,
            'AllAtOnceDeployment',
            {
                application,
                alias,
                deploymentConfig: codedeploy.LambdaDeploymentConfig.ALL_AT_ONCE,
            },
        );
```

Comment: Maybe you can extend [`Action`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.Action.html) for now?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do that? Sure I can create a construct that takes a new argument, but how'd that make it into the Cloud Formation Template? The only idea I have right now is to create a [Custom Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.CustomActionRegistration.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CodeDeploy and Lambda Action:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-codedeploy-readme.html for the general docs, specifically:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-codedeploy-readme.html#lambda-applications

Alternatively, if your program is not that complex and does not need all the additional overhead that CodeDeploy brings (having to synth the template and pass it to CodeDeploy and all) then just use a codebuild, that takes a source from your git repo and runs the command `cdk deploy your stack`

Comment: Added Code Snippet. I have the `LambdaDeploymentGroup` and `LambdaApplication` defined. The challenge is that it's a challenge to trigger that from CodePipeline.

Comment: use pipelines: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.StackDeployment.html